# Issue when trying to retrieve the access_token from Facebook

Tags: access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I have created a new application and am having an issue when trying to retrieve the access_token from facebook.

I am able to retrieve an auth code and generate the following request for the auth_token:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/ctfbesmokefree/&client_secret=APP_SECRET&code=GENERATED_CODE

I have followed the steps on this page:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=70773

However, even after following all the steps and editing the app settings I still receive the following error message when trying to generate an auth_token:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

Is there any other setting that needs to change or is there anything that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make a pattern like that:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&redirect_uri=&client_secret=&code=
which was good in your case and put one slash after your redirect url.

Example:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=402049XXXXX&client_secret=b943bfce7330fe4XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://www.prvnvrma.blogspot.in/&code=XXXXXXX;